# Microsoft Graph authentication fails on web API

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

We currently have a client(MVC .Net Core Web Application) and web API which is used to access Microsoft Graph calls, the authentication process uses Azure AD v2.0 endpoint. we can get this working if we do all of this in the client, however, as soon as we pass the token to the Web API this fails and doesn't even return a response to help us diagnose. below are loads of things we have tried, we have come to the conclusion our azure hasn't been set up correctly but unsure.

**Process 1 Works**

We forget the web API and do all actions inside the client, this method works but not what we are after so we know the code is not broken.

**Process 2 Fails**

1. Client Authenticates to Microsoft graph
2. redirects with code to the client
3. send the code to Web API to authenticate, get access token and refresh token
4. Fails returns nothing

**Process 3 Fails**

1. Client Authenticates to Microsoft graph
2. redirects with code to the client
3. send the code in the client to authenticate, get access token and refresh token
4. send access token and refresh token to Web API
5. use token to perform Microsoft graph action
6. Fails returns nothing

**Azure Settings**

Within Microsoft Azure, we have tried configuring the Microsoft Active Directory to follow [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof). However, this uses WPF and can't get this to work. We follow it step by step and even the user is prompted with the API permissions be still doesn't work. I am happy to provide any further information to help diagnose this issue.

Our architecture we are trying to achieve.
[image]

**Update**
This is where we exchange the authorization code for an access token however, this gives no return response and times out after about 100 seconds, doesn't even continue.

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"code", code},
                    {"client_id", _clientId},
                    {"client_secret", _clientSecret},
                    {"redirect_uri", _redirectUri},
                    {"grant_type", _codeGrantType}
                });

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(_tokenServerUrl, content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //get token from body and update expiry time...
                    var token = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<OAuthToken>();
                    token.ExpiresOn = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(token.ExpiresIn - 100);
                    return token;
                }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Are you using an access token for MS Graph API to call it?

Comment: @juunas we are not getting any error back in the code, it's like Microsoft completely ignores our request. We are using the code in the redirect URL, as we want a refresh token as well. This works if we do this all in the client, we want to authorize the web API as well.

Comment: @juunas I have added a code snippet of the exchange for an access token

Comment: @juunas i have looked at your example on GitHub and this is sort of what I want to achieve, the only difference is we pass the token to the web API from the client. from your experience do you know if anyone has achieved this?

Comment: It's a typical scenario. The client must acquire an access token for the API and the API needs to then exchange that token for an access token for MS Graph API using the on-behalf-of flow. Just make sure you send an access token from the client and not an id token as that can't be exchanged.

Comment: @juunas you might have pointed us in a direction we haven't tried. maybe our middle tier( our API)  doesn't have permissions to use the access token. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#gaining-consent-for-the-middle-tier-application) could be of use, does that sound correct?

Comment: Yeah that's the docs for how to get consent for your API essentially.